# jQuery Toggling when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I got myself this far and I've solved the problem I was having but I'd still like to know why this is.

First, here is my original code:

```
$(function(){
    var navListLength = $('nav ul li').length;

    buttonPress(1);
    function buttonPress(i){

        if(i < navListLength){

            $('nav ul li a:nth-child(' + i + ')').click(function(){
                $(this).toggleClass('button-pressed');

                console.log('Button Down');

                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('nav ul li a:nth-child(' + i + ')').toggleClass('button-pressed');

                    buttonPress(i + 1);
                    console.log('Button Up');

                }, 500);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

It's supposed to toggle the style of a single link in a navigation list when it's clicked and not affect any other links in the list.

I wanted to do it this way so that I could add any amount of links to this list in the future without having to create a new a new class and add it to the jQuery each time.

The first toggle works as expected. But the second toggle is being applied to all of the links and it creates an inverted effect. So all of the links are opposite of what they are supposed to be except the link being clicked.

I solved the problem by changing the first toggleClass to addClass and the second toggleClass to removeClass. But I shouldn't have to do that.

Could anyone tell me why this is?

Here's a picture of my buttons:

[image: My menu buttons]

Comment: Why are you calling `setTimeout()`? That's probably where your immediate issue lies, since `buttonPress()` is called on `i + 1` making it recursive, but this code seems way over-complicated for simply toggling a class on a click event anyways.

Comment: I wanted to toggle a class then un-toggle it 500ms later to make it look like the button was "springy." Is there a better way to do it? This was the way that was suggested to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing way too much work just to toggle a class on click. You don't need to make an array of all the navigation items, the whole point of jQuery is that it handles selecting DOM elements for you.

Try this:

```
$(function() {

  $('nav ul li').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('button-pressed');
  });

});
```

You don't have to handle making sure the others aren't affected. Only the clicked element gets toggled.

-- EDIT --

I see what you were going for with the `setTimeout()` now. You can do it inside the click handler, like this:

```
  $('nav ul li').click(function() {
    // store the selection in a variable
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('button-pressed');
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $this.toggleClass('button-pressed');
    }, 500);
  });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/84Zcn/2/)

Comment: Your code toggles all the li elements. I don't want that. Just a single li. I also want to un-toggle the same button .5s later to make it look springy.

Comment: It should just toggle the one element. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84Zcn/). Click the list items, only the one you click changes class.

Comment: I figured out why I needed to do it this way. Since I want a delay, and set timeout doesn't stop and hold a function from completing, I needed it in a loop, but the loop broke the jQuery, I think, which I why I added incremented class names.

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't stop and hold a function from completely"

Comment: Typo, sorry. Check the edit. Ah, yeah. That works. I swear there was a reason for the recursive loop though. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Why now in pure CSS like:

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/dasiy/1/edit)**

```
 <span class="button" tabindex="1"> 
   <span>Home</span>
 </span>
```

```
span.button{
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:9px;
  background:#ddd;
  padding:6px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  outline:none;
}
span.button > span{
  background:#F06BAE;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 25px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom:4px solid #CB4589;
  transition: border 0.3s;
}
span.button:focus > span{
  border-top: 4px solid #FCA9D2;
  border-bottom-width:0;
}
```

Comment: Fancy, how about springing back as OP mentioned? I feel like it's going to get to be a tangle of css, though. And IE support? forget it, 10+ I think

Comment: @j ? did not understand that part out of the Question as it stands... :(

Comment: I don't think he mentioned IE, but it is unfortunately always a consideration. I just feel like for something that is so simple in jQuery it's overkill to write 50ish lines of css to pull it off.

Comment: @jshanley just one line in my example `transition: border 0.3s;`. The other CSS is quite needed to follow the button design...